# PyMongo TypeError - document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Tags: python, pymongo, geojson

When I'm trying to insert a chunk of GeoJSON into MongoDB, I received this message: `TypeError - document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or other type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping` .

The chunk is like this:

```
new_points = ['{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}', '{"coordinates": [-179.75, 89.75], "simulation": "aet_whe", "type": "Point"}']
```

And the insert call was this:

```
result = points.insert_many(new_points)
```

This dictionary was generated with GeoJson library, using this structure:

```
class GenerateDocument:
    def __init__(self, x, y, simulation_variable):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.sim = simulation_variable

    @property
    def __geo_interface__(self):
        return {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (self.x, self.y), 'simulation': self.sim}
```

Any hint to solve this? Am I generating a wrong type of geojson?

Comment: Looks like a list of strings to me. Perhaps you should `[json.loads(coords) for coords in new_points]` first and pass that instead?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist It worked! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the suggestion : `[json.loads(coords) for coords in new_points]` on `new_points` variable solves the problem.